# How can I fix CURL quotes strpos() problem?

Tags: php, curl

Firstly, sorry my bad English. 
I'm taking text from a site with Curl. After that, I am searching in text some words with strpos().

But; when text coming with quotes, my function is not working. For example. Text is coming with curl without quotes;

```
$text = "This is my text.";
$intext = "This is";

if (strpos($text, $intext) !== false) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Okey, page give me "OK", now my codes working.
But, when text coming with quotes like this:

```
$text = "This's my text.";
$intext = "This's my";

if (strpos($text, $intext) !== false) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

The page gives me: "NO"!

Why? I think the quotation mark data from the website is different. How can I fix this problem? I need to compare without clearing punctuation.

Comment: Note: 
Text comes from a site with curl. It normally works when you write these codes to the editor. 
Problem; The $text variable is different from the quotation marks in the data.

Comment: The code works fine: https://3v4l.org/Zq6lD you might be getting different styles of quotes in the curl response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed problem with this code;

```
$str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_COMPAT , 'UTF-8');
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
$text = strip_tags($str);
```

Thanks.